# Javascript newbie stuck with XMLHttpRequest return data

Tags: javascript

It's probably over a decade since last I played around with JavaScript, so here goes. I am trying to display a graph from either my back-end database and/or my ESP32 micro-controller. Easy to generate a static HTML/CSS/JavaScript graph from and example, but I need the graph to update with real time data every second. I can get the JavaScript to call the database via XMLHttpRequest and it returns the data, but I have no clue about how to get it back into the variable that updates the graph.

I found more or less the charts that I require for a project on https://www.amcharts.com/.

```
// using chart.setTimeout method as the timeout will be disposed together with a chart
 chart.setTimeout(randomValue, 1000);

function randomValue() {
    //hand.showValue(Math.random() * 1000, 1000, am4core.ease.cubicOut); // <----- sample code supplied
    //hand.showValue(550); // <---- my test code which works

    // after some googling I found this...
    function reqListener () {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    //alert(oReq.responseText); // <---- when un-commented I can see my data that the database is returning every second, just an integer value and nothing else.
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    oReq.open("GET", 'http://myurl.com');
    oReq.send();

    hand.showValue(oReq.responseText); <<<<<< what do I put in the () to show the same data that the alert above displays correctly?

    chart.setTimeout(randomValue, 1000); // < original supplied sample code
}
```

Nothing happens... and I don't have a clue :)

Comment: Move `hand.showValue(oReq.responseText);` inside `function reqListener ()`

Comment: In short: You just can't. As a sidenote, I warmly recommend using [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) nowadays.

Comment: "
Move hand.showValue(oReq.responseText); inside function reqListener () – rodrigoap 46 mins ago
I tried that but it did not work - thanks

Comment: As I said it's been a while since last I looked at JavaScript. I will have a look at fetch() thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` requires you to add an event listener and wait for the `load` event. This will tell you once the request has completed and then you can do something with the response.

Take a look at this website for a more detailed description:
https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest

Comment: Got it working but the console gives an error : InvalidStateError: responseText is only available if responseType is '' or 'text'.